# Find parent of control inside ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code that I am trying to find a Parent "NodeItem" from the child control which is inside a Content presenter.

```
private static DependencyObject GetParentObject(DependencyObject child)
        {
            if(child == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var result = child as NodeItem;
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }

            ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
            if(contentElement != null)
            {
                DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
                if(parent != null)
                {
                    return GetParentObject(parent);
                }
            }

            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            if(fe != null)
            {
                DependencyObject parent = fe.Parent;
                if(parent != null)
                {
                    return GetParentObject(parent);
                }
            }
            return GetParentObject(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child));
        }
```

And here is visual tree from snoop.

[screenshot of visual tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LizSy.png)

I have OnDrop handled on the label and I want to access the nodeitem from inside that event handler.

here is XAML

```
<Grid>
                        <!--
                            This border indicates that node is selected.
                            Normally it is transparent, but when 'IsSelected' is set
                            to 'true' the border brush becomes blue and its background
                            becomds light blue.
                        -->
                        <Border
                            x:Name="selectionBorder"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="2">
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect
                                                Opacity="0.1"
                                                ShadowDepth="1"
                                                Color="#FF151414" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>

                            <!--
                                User-defined node content is presented here.
                            -->
                            <ContentPresenter />

                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
```

Content Presenter is later replaced with an another grid with controls shown in the tree.

Comment: Please paste your xaml.

Comment: Please check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c47754bd-38c7-40b3-b64a-38a48884fde8/how-to-find-a-parent-of-a-specific-type?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks @swamy it worked. if you can post it as answer I will mark it.

Comment: I've added it as answer for reference from the link. 
BTW, a quick google search would have given you the answer. Please do some research before asking the questions. I'm sure some of them have faced a similar problem and found the solution. If you couldn't find any working answers for you then post the question.

Comment: I did search and had tried.. If you see my question I have code also in there. It is not something I posted blindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found on MSDN: [How to find a Parent of a Specific Type](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c47754bd-38c7-40b3-b64a-38a48884fde8/how-to-find-a-parent-of-a-specific-type?forum=wpf).

```
private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child)    
where T : DependencyObject    
{    
   T parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as T;    
   if (parent != null)
   {
      return parent;
   }
   else
   {
      return FindParent<T>(parent);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Bug in the previous code sample, fixed below:

```
private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
  DependencyObject immediateParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
  T parent = immediateParent as T;
  if (parent != null)
    return parent;
  else
    return FindParent<T>(immediateParent);
}
```